# Unable to suggest edits on a closed question

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, suggested-edits

**[Backstory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2286/5029)**

TL;DR: It was discovered on Gaming that I cannot suggest edits on a closed question.  I can edit open posts and >2k rep users can edit the closed post.

Is the fact that I am unable to suggest edits on a closed question by design or a bug?

Comment: This is correct. Closed questions cannot be edited by users without full edit privileges. As to whether this is by design, I cannot say.

Comment: I suspect this is by design, but good question.

Comment: This isn't in the [suggested edit FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284), but should be, if “can't suggest edits to a closed question” is indeed what is implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just pushed a change that allows this.

This was by-design however it seems people dislike this design. I do want us to allow people to clean up tags on old closed questions.

Comment: will be deployed today

Comment: Thank you!  What was the reasoning for making it behave this way in the first place?

Comment: @John ... my gut ... but it seems to have been wrong

Comment: @waffles, I wanted to suggest an edit to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845636) as per the post [on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100804) to help remove the 'rant' portions to help future users of PhpStorm. But I can't.  The link isn't there.  Should I open a bug report?

Comment: Is an answered question considered closed (when OP accepts an answer as correct)? I got a message saying that I cannot edit a question. Only thing I noticed was, it had been answered.

Answer (score 7):

It's really frustrating on the sites that I'm not 2k, to see closed questions that need the tags changed and not being able to.  Some of them were migrated from other sites, and have tags that don't even exist on the site they were migrated to.

**Please enable suggested edits on any question that a user can see.**

Here's a [sample question](https://superuser.com/questions/282028/copying-email-addresses-from-to-field-to-excel-closed) on Super User that should have the [microsoft-excel](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) (yeh, I know it should be [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), but Super User did it differently), but a user who couldn't edit tags couldn't do anything about it.  This isn't end-of-the-world stuff, but for those of us who like to clean things up, it's frustrating.