# Casting the final close vote on a question clears a pending suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, suggested-edits, closed-questions

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827951/iphone-select-one-button-and-remaining-button-informartion-is-nill) that was begging to be closed, and already had 4 other close votes. While I was performing the necessary ritual to add mine, I noticed that there was a pending suggested edit.

I reasoned that the question still needed to be closed until the original asker came back to clarify what exactly he or she was looking for, so I decided to close first and examine the suggested edit afterwards.

Clearly that was the wrong order in which to do things. As soon as I cast the final close vote, the page refreshed, and the pending suggested edit seemed to have *vanished*.

There was no indication of it in the "edit" link, I couldn't find it in the master suggested edit queue, and I don't even see it in the suggested edit stats (under the 10k tools). And I know it wasn't approved by someone else in the meantime, because the question shows no indication of having been edited.

I'm not really sure if that particular edit was any good or whether it's worth expending much effort trying to revive it. But **I *was* surprised to see that when a question is closed, all pending suggested edits seem to be rejected and removed from the queue. Is this by design, or a bug?**

A month ago, I would have assumed this was by design, as we didn't support suggesting edits to closed questions. But [this has since been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92614/unable-to-suggest-edits-on-a-closed-question) (a positive change, I think), so maybe this is something that missed getting fixed at the same time.

Comment: Nice catch, looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Are you sure that the edit wasn't rejected while you were casting your close vote?

Comment: @Belinda: Not completely sure, no. But if that's the case, I should have found it in the suggested edit stats (under the 10k tools). As I mentioned in my question, I didn't see it listed there, either as approved or rejected. That makes me suspect that it was *deleted* by the system, rather than approved/rejected through standard channels.

Comment: This is still happening as of Sep 5, 2011. I misunderstood where you said "this has since been fixed," so I posted a duplicate [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105158/suggested-edit-may-have-been-borked-by-closure). In my case, the question was closed by a mod, not five regular users.

Comment: I think the reasoning is migrations, will change it so it special cases migrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is an edge case where we want to reject suggested edit.

If the post happens to be migrated to another site, we can not leave the suggestion in the queue, but then again it is deleted so it is handled in other code.

I went ahead and disabled the auto reject. It was legacy.

Comment: `me.getVocabulary().drop("it was old-school"); me.getVocabulary().add("it was legacy");`

Comment: [Looks like dropping the auto-reject was necessary after all.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/suggested-edit-presented-with-no-possible-actions)

Comment: @Gilles yeah ... the thing is that after a migration it is not deleted for a while ... I think locking a post should simply auto reject everything - that would fix this issue

Comment: Maybe it makes sense after all? At least if the question is closed as a dupe, the Community stealth edit somewhat [interferes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130523/the-dupe-link-edit-by-community-interferes-with-suggested-edits) with suggested edits.