# Can a question or an answer be deleted when it has a pending revision?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, vote-to-delete

When someone posts a bad question or answer, and it has earned some down votes,
then another user suggests an edit to it, and the post is pending:

- In this situation, can anyone start a delete vote on it?
- When a post is in delete voting, can anyone suggest an edit for it?
- When a suggest edit is pending, it is deleted (either via the consensus of three users or the direct action of a single moderator), then how a bout the pending version? **Is it stay in suggest edit queue**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** Delete votes can be cast on questions/answers that have pending suggested edits, and edits can be suggested on posts that have delete votes cast against them.

But of course, once a question or answer has been deleted (either via the consensus of three users or the direct action of a single moderator), you can no longer suggest edits to that post. Users who do not have full editing privileges (and thus must suggest edits for approval) also do not have sufficient privileges to view deleted questions/answers. 10k users *can* edit deleted posts, but since they have full editing privileges, they do not have to suggest their edits for approval.

Comment: When a suggest edit is pending, it is deleted (either via the consensus of three users or the direct action of a single moderator), then how a bout the pending version? Is it stay in suggest edit queue?

Comment: @Roy: I'm not sure about that, actually. I suspect that the pending edit is removed from the queue. That's what happens when a question is closed (although I'm [currently wondering if this is actually by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99875/casting-the-final-close-vote-on-a-question-clears-a-pending-suggested-edit)), so I imagine the same thing happens for a suggested edit when the post is deleted.