# Suggested edit may have been borked by closure

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, vote-to-close, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting the final close vote on a question clears a pending suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99875/casting-the-final-close-vote-on-a-question-clears-a-pending-suggested-edit)

I just suggested an edit to [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/332193/does-wordpress-have-to-open-source-just-because-it-uses-mysql). When I returned to the question a few minutes later, it was closed as a duplicate, and there was no evidence that I had ever suggested an edit.

That would be just fine if some >2k user or moderator had rejected my edit independently of closure. However, I didn't see the post in [my "recent edit suggestions" list](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/5265). That made me think that the act of closing automatically rejected the edit. I consider this a bug because a suggested edit could, in theory, improve a bad question enough to make it not-close-worthy. That wouldn't have been true in my specific case, but that's not important.

Through the magic of manual URL modification, I found [the history of my suggested edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/5278). It's listed as "Rejected," but there's nobody listed under "Reviewer," not even the Community user.

Things that might be relevant, but probably aren't:

- the same user asked the question I tried to edit and the question it was closed as a duplicate of
- the duplicate question was posted at 17:55:29
- the duplicate question was migrated to WordPress SE at 19:04:00
- the question I tried to edit was closed at 19:04:47

Comment: Dang it. I misunderstood the meaning of "this has since been fixed" on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99875/casting-the-final-close-vote-on-a-question-clears-a-pending-suggested-edit). The end result is that this question is a duplicate of that one. I'll vote to close this, but leave it undeleted in case something I provided turns out to be useful. For example, in my case, the close happened because of a binding mod vote, not a five-regular-users decision.