# Suggested edit presented with no possible actions

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I was reviewing suggested edits when I ran across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/101993) ([to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328603/remove-lord-rahul-cool-virus-migrated)):

[image]

I expected to see some Approve or Reject buttons, but instead, it sits there just daring me to try *anything*. It's survived a few refreshes. It might as well be wearing a troll face.

EDIT: the question was migrated, likely after the suggested edit was made.

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/102779

Comment: Also happens with tag wiki, see here including screenshot: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105792/migrating-a-question-causes-suggested-edit-to-be-stuck-in-pending-state

Comment: … and another one: http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/5797

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was happening on locked posts.

I changed it so when a post is locked all suggested edits are rejected by the community user with the note:

> Post was locked - suggested edit can not be processed

Answer (score 7):

That happens whenever a post is locked after the edit is submitted. Locking happens either when a question is migrated or (rarely) when a moderator hit the “lock” button. I believe suggested edits are deleted when a question is deleted, though there may be a race condition if the edit is submitted close to the time of deletion.

[The behavior of suggested edits on migrated questions was changed recently.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99875/casting-the-final-close-vote-on-a-question-clears-a-pending-suggested-edit/105194#105194) Looks like a bug crept in then.