# Post stuck in the edit queue after migration to Tex.SE

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested edit presented with no possible actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/suggested-edit-presented-with-no-possible-actions)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592995/clean-up-temporary-files-after-pdf-is-generated?noredirect=1) was migrated to [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29888/clean-up-temporary-files-after-pdf-is-generated) 17 hours ago, and the edit that was made to the question (which is reflected on the Tex side) is stuck in the Stack Overflow edit queue without accept/reject/improve buttons.

How do we get rid of these?  Do they need to be reported?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yes, I seem to remember you bringing this up before. I couldn't remember if yours was related to migration, though.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I don't think either of those two I added in were really addressed in the answers to your question

Comment: I fixed the specific one ... will look at a more complete fix

Comment: @waffles There's another one http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/122113 that got migrated to Meta