# Don't show the suggested edits for questions that have been migrated

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested edit presented with no possible actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/suggested-edit-presented-with-no-possible-actions)

Looking at the [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review), I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/114204):

[image: screenshot]

It is not possible to reject the edit, nor is possible to approve it because the question has been migrated.

Suggested edits for migrated questions should not appear in the "review" page.

Comment: Related: [Suggested edit presented with no possible actions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105325)

Comment: Also, waffles is [looking into it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107918/post-stuck-in-the-edit-queue-after-migration-to-tex-se#comment-278029).