# Question is stuck in the review queue for edits to approve and the buttons are missing

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested edit presented with no possible actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/suggested-edit-presented-with-no-possible-actions)

I see at the moment [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/worst-practices-in-developing-database-applications) with an edit to approve in the [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day), but the buttons to handle this edit are missing.

The edit was suggested 2 hours ago. Also about 2 hours ago it was migrated to Programmers and 1 hour ago it was closed. But still the edit is in the review queue, the buttons are missing, I see no possibility to handle this edit.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if editing it in programmers would fix it.