# Suggested edit "sticks" in queue after parent post is locked

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, locked

There's a suggested edit in the MSO queue right now that I can't act on:

[image: The edit as it appears on the review page.]

This is how it appears to the user who made the edit:

[image: The edit as it appears to the user who made it.]

The suggestion was submitted at 20:19:19Z. Robert Harvey locked the post at 20:24:57Z. (To be completely accurate, this is an answer, and Robert locked the parent question, so it got locked by association.) Is this edit doomed to sit in the queue forever, untouchable by anyone who would free it from limbo?

Here's a [convenient direct link to the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42064/131713).

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/suggested-edit-presented-with-no-possible-actions), but it was supposedly fixed. I guess "locked by association" wasn't taken into account

Comment: Huh. I even remembered that post but didn't complete the mental connection. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. The issue at hand was resolved in 2012, so you should not be experiencing it with the current build of our sites.