# Locked posts appear in review queues

Tags: bug, review, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New beta Review displays locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141435/new-beta-review-displays-locked-posts)

I couldn't find a question of which this is an exact duplicate. So here it is.

[image: picture of bug]

Suggesting people to review something they cannot act on is… useless. Right?

This is a harmless but annoying bug (taken from the *late answers* list, if it matters). Bugbusters?

Comment: You may have been looking for [Suggested edit presented with no possible actions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/suggested-edit-presented-with-no-possible-actions), or maybe [Suggested edit “sticks” in queue after parent post is locked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127907/suggested-edit-sticks-in-queue-after-parent-post-is-locked). I don't know of an existing bug report for the review (as opposed to suggested edit) queue.

Comment: @Pop: Yes, I'm talking about review lists, which is different and needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: The new /review is what we're using going forward and this has been addressed in the dupe.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Ahah, I haven't searched for duplicates thoroughly, I should also have looked ahead four months in the future :)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Make time travel a part of your daily routine. :)