# New beta Review displays locked posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, locked

I've seen the other questions on the subject, just letting you know it exists here as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/68769

It shows an answer from the locked cartoon thread. Shouldn't the filter ignore those?

Comment: Ugh... was that undeleted because Joel said this is the best rated list on programmer cartoons in a podcast? Is there also a best rated favourite toilet paper to wipe your butt... as a programmer list? If not, we should totally have one. Or maybe print these cartoons and...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locked posts are excluded from the Low Quality Posts queue now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: [Still happening, at least on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/966): ran into a few of them recently.

Comment: Just ran into [another one on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/review-beta/late-answers/26898). It is dated well after this answer, so I do not believe this is entirely fixed.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: @Emmett [Still happening on ProgSE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/960) (and the [mod dialog doesn't work](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/mod-dialog-in-review-doesnt-show-up-properly-and-a-bonus-feature-request)).

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear; they're appearing in the Late Answers queue (as well).

Comment: Happened to me on Serverfault a few minutes ago. Perhaps the queue should be wiped clean of any closed answers?

Comment: Ok, I just fixed up the SQL queries we're using for all 5 review queues; locked questions, as well as answers of locked questions, shouldn't be showing up any more.

Comment: @Emmett Is this [status-completed] for ProgSE as well? Haven't seen a locked posted in /review past few days, but...

Comment: [Locked posts still appearing in ProgSE's review queues](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/review-audit-quality)...