# Add a mod link to review tasks

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, review

When digging through the Low Quality review list on UX I've often itched for my mod tools; convert to comment and Post Notice are the big ones.

Consider the following answer:

[image]

Depending on the situation, this might be outright junk (delete), it might be a comment (convert), or it might just be a plain old no-explaination answer (in need of a post notice). This one happens to be in need of a post notice (never mind the age...it's an example).

I can go to `link` on the right and perform a mod action through there, but it'd be nice if there was a tiny little `mod` link like mods see on all posts so I could easily slap a notice on there and hit "looks good".

I understand keeping the UI minimal and focused, but this is a tiny (familiar) link only <1% of users will ever see, and it'll help streamline the review process for mods.

Answer (score 6):

The next build will include a mod menu for moderators who are in the review queue.

Comment: This is a nice feature, but why is it redirecting me to the question when I convert an answer to a comment instead of keeping me in review?

Comment: We'll see if we can make this better, but right now it mirrors the behavior used on an actual question page.

Comment: makes sense. Just breaks the workflow right now.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Mod link, yay! Small UI snafu on Programmers though, z-index is a bit off, mod popup is unusable (only partially visible). Oh, and we still see [low quality answers on locked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141435/162704)...