# Using moderator actions when reviewing posts shouldn't kick you out of the Review page

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, review, moderator-tools

As described briefly in this [comment discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143481/add-a-mod-link-to-review-tasks#comment412536_144515), currently if you perform a moderator action such as 'convert to comment' from the Mod link on the new review system, the page refreshes onto the question and you are taken out of the Review page.  Less importantly it's also not counted as a review action.

I realise that in the comments it does say that this will be worked on, however *it's been six to eight weeks* so I thought bringing it up as a feature-request would be appropriate.

**Could the review system be changed so that moderator actions can be performed without breaking the review workflow?**

Comment: Another mod action where I find this annoying is the "add citation needed banner" on Skeptics, [I reported this also a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148386/adding-a-post-notice-makes-me-exit-the-review-queue).

Comment: See my answer on @MadScientist's bug report.

Comment: This needs to be fixed in the flag queue, too. Most annoying thing *especially* on a site as big as SO!

Answer (score 1):

I've updated most mod popup actions to keep you on the queue if that's where you came from.

This should be out there in the next build.