# Taking moderator action in the Low Quality review queue redirects to the question instead of back to the queue

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using moderator actions when reviewing posts shouldn’t kick you out of the Review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151348/using-moderator-actions-when-reviewing-posts-shouldnt-kick-you-out-of-the-revie)

The mod link is a nice addition, giving diamond moderators an extra set of actions we can take directly from the review queue.  It breaks the normal review workflow though, because it redirects back to the question page after a moderator action, instead of taking us back to the next item up for bid in the review queue.  Can we get that redirect to mimic the normal review workflow?

Comment: ["We're aware that the mod-menu-from-review flow is sub-optimal, and it's on our TODO. We just haven't prioritized it to the top yet, since it affects a small minority of users (albeit important ones)."](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/4054/25936)

Comment: Personally, I think we could borrow more elements of the Space Invaders UI for moderators in the review queue.