# Moderator actions on items in the review queues don't count towards the review totals

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools

When I'm checking the review queues as a moderator - particularly the Low Quality Posts queue - I'm presented with an extra link beside the question `mod`. This gives me access to the moderator tools which include the "convert to comment option".

A valid option for some low quality answers is the option to convert them to a comment on the question. However, selecting the mod tools and that option

1. [Throws me out of the Review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151348/using-moderator-actions-when-reviewing-posts-shouldnt-kick-you-out-of-the-revie)
2. Doesn't count towards my review total.

Now I know it's not much in the scheme of things, but I *have* reviewed that question. The only workaround I have is to

1. Open the page in a new tab
2. Use the delete button to increment the review count.
3. Switch to the other tab
4. Undelete the answer
5. Use the mod tools to convert it to a comment.

Needless to say I'm *not* doing this as life's just too short, but it does annoy me that I'm not getting any closer to the Reviewer or Steward badge in that queue.

Comment: The non-ajax thing also extremely annoys me on the regular mod queue. It is **so** annoying especially when the only comment on a non-answer is "should be a comment"

Answer (score 8):

The workaround I use is to leave a comment stating *'I'm converting this to a comment for you as you don't have rep'* or whatever, because then you've left a useful comment *and* it would count towards the review total. Then go to the post in question and convert to a comment. (Possibly opening it in a new tab before doing this I guess to save hunting for it in the main queue)

As I always look to leave comments against posts I'm closing / deleting / etc then it's only one extra step, rather than the delete/undelete option you've suggested.

But yes, it is still a bit of a workaround too and not much quicker than your route (probably longer actually as you have to leave a comment) but I think it's a more useful route to take.

Comment: +1 for the workaround, but that's too many clicks (but that's not your fault).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to that - as a Mod we get two separate pages to review from:

1. The main "Review" queue
2. The Moderator Diamond

If I review an item from the appropriate review queue, my count goes up, however if I moderate the item from the Moderator Diamond the appropriate review count doesn't increase.

The only reason I bring this up is I'm a pro-tem mod, and if our site comes out of beta and we hold proper elections, our review queues aren't accurate.

As an example:

[My "public" reviews](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/56/zhaph-ben-duguid?tab=activity&sort=reviews):
[image: Public review actions, last action yesterday]

Compared with my Mod actions:
[image: Action via Mod Diamond]

All because I forgot to go through the "Review" option :(

Comment: Good point about not having accurate statistics for the moderator election, though you are still a pro-tem mod during the election (unless you stood down at some point of course) so people should be aware that the reviews don't reflect all you do.

Comment: True enough, but "should" is the operative word ;)