# Pathway for review breaks on double peer reviewed edit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I was just reviewing on [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and had an experience which is likely a rare use case but thought I'd bring it up as it's not entirely right.  It took me a while but I have also been able to reproduce this on [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Steps to reproduce (using an account **without** the edit privilege):

1. Find a review post that should be edited (I used first post in both instances)
2. Suggest an edit to that post, then submit it for peer review.
3. You are then correctly returned to the review item in question.
4. Notice another problem that you have forgotten to fix and submit another edit to peer review (which gets merged with your previous edit).
5. **This time you are returned to the post itself outside of review and get no credit for the review**.

For reference the posts I encountered this on were:

- Gaming [Suggested Edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31443)
- Android [Suggested Edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16556)

To clarify, I would I think have been able to click "I'm Done" had I not changed my suggested edit.  The question has disappeared from my review queue in both cases after I submitted the edit (though I had not clicked any of the buttons on the item).

Update: The post has appeared in the Android queue shuffled out of order, with the edit still showing the peer review banner and all three buttons enabled ("No action needed", "I'm Done", "Skip").

*Possibly related to [Using moderator actions when reviewing posts shouldn't kick you out of the Review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151348/using-moderator-actions-when-reviewing-posts-shouldnt-kick-you-out-of-the-revie) (which is status completed).*