# The "dupe link" edit by Community interferes with suggested edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, duplicate-questions, community-user

<sub><sup>(Or maybe the suggested edits interfere with the dupe link, I guess that also works.)</sup></sub>

This is something I've seen happening a couple times, [such as here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/130522/revisions).

When an edit is suggested *before*, and reviewed *after* the question is closed as a duplicate, the edit will appear to remove the "Possible Duplicate" box that is automatically [added by Community](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

[image]

This happens due to a clashing edit situation that is *usually* impossible — normal users can't suggest edits while another one is already pending, and those with edit rights are forced to approve or reject it first.

However, Community is highly rude and just performs the edit anyway.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99875/casting-the-final-close-vote-on-a-question-clears-a-pending-suggested-edit); apparently closing a question used to dismiss edits, possibly for this reason.

Comment: It's that rude Community user again! Can we just ban him and get it over with?

Comment: Just noticed this as well. Also when the edit was not accepted yet, but you want to *improve* it, the duplicate link is removed as well.

Comment: This happened to me. I voted to close from a review queue (I think at this point the question had been flagged but had no close votes) then went back and edited (since editing from the close review would remove it from that queue) and then my edit was not as substantial as the "possible duplicate" that community added because I voted to close. If Community is going to do that, could it be a little quicker?

Comment: Duplicate links are no longer inserted as edits, so this shouldn't be a problem anymore.