# Suggested edit removes automatically inserted duplicate link

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The “dupe link” edit by Community interferes with suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130523/the-dupe-link-edit-by-community-interferes-with-suggested-edits)

See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/2837/revisions

Normally, when a post has a suggested edit, editing is disabled to avoid edit conflicts. However, Community♦ is exempt from this, and can edit in the "possible duplicate" hat note even when there is a pending suggested edit.

Which means that approving the edit kills the dupe hatnote (I thought that the hatnote would be auto-inserted into the edit, so I approved it to check--it wasn't)

Could this be changed so that the dupe header is injected into all suggested edits on a post after closing?

Comment: Can this happen while an edit that is not subject to review is in progress?

Comment: @Asad: Not sure. IIRC the system lets you know that the post was edited x times when you try to add your own edit.

Comment: (I know this is a feature request, but I think the behaviour is buggy as implied in the linked post)